# Odoo - How to get a pre-created record/value in many2one field

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

How can I select/get a pre created record/value in many2one field

for example: the `holidays_status_id` in `hr_holidays` module is a many2one field and it has already 4 values of

1. Legal Leaves
2. Sick Leaves
3. Compensatory Days
4. Unpaid

what I need to do is dynamically select the legal leaves and customize it in another module.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the data is coming after once you are installing the module of your hr_holidays.It means the part of first time of module installation.

It is basically a part of the data file which is named as `hr_holidays_data.xml` file in hr_holidays module.

It must need to add that file location on 'data' key attribute of value in `__openerp__.py` file

```
'data': ['hr_holidays_data.xml']
```

which is part of added into our module menifiest file of each module in Odoo (Formally OpenERP).

```
<!-- Casual leave -->
<record model="hr.holidays.status" id="holiday_status_cl">
    <field name="name" eval="'Legal Leaves '+time.strftime('%Y')"/>
    <field name="color_name">black</field>
</record>

<!-- Sick leave -->
<record model="hr.holidays.status" id="holiday_status_sl">
    <field name="name">Sick Leaves</field>
    <field name="limit">True</field>
    <field name="color_name">red</field>
</record>

<!-- Compensatory Days -->
<record model="hr.holidays.status" id="holiday_status_comp">
    <field name="name">Compensatory Days</field>
    <field name="limit">True</field>
    <field name="color_name">lavender</field>
</record>

<!--Unpaid Leave -->
<record model="hr.holidays.status" id="holiday_status_unpaid">
    <field name="name">Unpaid</field>
    <field name="limit">True</field>
    <field name="color_name">brown</field>
</record>
```

Need to understand the following attribute for more clarification.

**1. model :-**
which is part of the your own model (class name) or use the existing Odoo Model class.which is basically mentioned on each class of **_name** attribute in your class.

**2. id :**
unique id of each record

**2.field name:**
what ever field you want to add a new record (insert a new record) which is part of the model class fields name.

Each record contain the number of child field name so you can add as per your requirement and do to check after install or upgrade the module.

You may also add our own custom leave with our module with our own separate .xml file and add it as per your need.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)